# Highchart x-axis custom timedate label

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I have datapoints for highchart that looks like this [2016-10-05 03:00:00,1], but I cant make my x-axis format the date correct and show it as a label. It seems like its just counting from 1.jan 1970 and forward.

```
xAxis: {
   type: 'datetime',
    title: {
        text: 'Dato'
    },
    format: '{value:%Y-%m-%d %H}',
    tickWidth: 1,
    labels: {
    rotation: -45,
    style: {
        fontSize: '13px',
        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
    }
}
```

The strange this is that the tooltip shows the format correct.

[image: graph]

EDIT
The millisecond helped a great deal. I only think im missing somekind of Interval
[image]

Comment: Highcharts expects date to be in the format of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970. Do you have this format of your x values?

Comment: *"It seems like its just counting from 1.jan 1970 and forward."* Yes, this is `epoch` time. If your dates aren't formatted properly, Highcharts can't read them, and use the index position of the data point as the x value, which would increment 1 millisecond per data point.   Epoch ref: http://www.epochconverter.com

Comment: That helped a lot, thanks :) Now i just want to show it for each hour, even though there is no data on that hour

Comment: The chart will only plot a point where you tell it...what would you want it to do for the hours without data? If you want it to show a zero value, you will have to process the data and insert the zero values at the appropriate points.

Comment: Good point.. but I made it work now, thanks all for the help :)